# Easy way to parse time and speed output from mbuffer?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have `mbuffer` to put its output into a file. One line per file, where 3 examples could be

```
summary:  0.0 KiByte in  0.3 sec - average of  0.0 B/s
summary:  0.0 KiByte in  12 h 24 min - average of  12.0 KiB/s
summary:  0.0 KiByte in  12 min - average of  12.0 MiB/s
```

I would like to extract the time in seconds and the speed in MB/s.

**Question**

Is there an easy way to do this? Because I can only think of something that would give a very long regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/summary:.*?in\s*(?:(?<hours>[\d\.]+) h)?\s*(?:(?<minutes>[\d\.]+) min)?\s*(?:(?<seconds>[\d\.]+) sec)?.*?average of\s*(?<speed>[\d\.]+ [a-zA-Z]+\/s)/g`

..would create 4 named capturing groups:

- `seconds` (that contains seconds, eg. `0.3`)
- `minutes` (that contains minutes, eg. `24`)
- `hours` (that contains hours, eg. `12`)
- `speed` (the average speed with the B/KiB/MiB appended, eg. `12.0 KiB/s`)

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/jH9qO9)

**Output**:

[image]